# Attacker's AC effect on pummeling attacks

Tags: adnd-1e, unarmed-combat

On page 72 of the DMG under Pummel - Base Score to Hit, it says

> Attacker's AC, per point, with negative AC being treated as
> positive by type* +1%
> ...
>
> * Magical protections such as rings ... do not count as AC, so ignore them; encumbrance = AC 10

I take this to mean if the attacker is unarmored, they have a 10% bonus to their attack roll. Plate Mail gives a 3% bonus. Cool, got it!

My questions are as follows:

1. If I have a dexterity bonus of -2 to my AC, does that lower my chances to hit by 2%?
2. What is "positive by type"? Does an AC of -1 from enchanted Plate Mail +4 just give the Plate Mail bonus of 3%?
3. Do magical bonuses from armor or shield affect this calculation - they aren't rings or bracers?
4. Does the attacker being encumbered (by how much?) give a 10% bonus regardless of what armor they are wearing?
5. Why didn't Gary just hire an editor (You don't have to answer this one :P )

Comment: Regarding close votes: These questions are related to a single point about a single rule in the original DMG. This is a complex combat system and so demands a complex question. Sorry.

Comment: *Why didn't Gary just hire an editor* ? He did: Mike Carr. (I think he's still alive). 

Answer (score 3):

This is a very unclear way of writing "+1% per point of armour type". Your armour *type* is the armour *class* you would have without magical bonuses, Dexterity modifiers, or anything else. It's the part of armour class that comes purely from the armour you're wearing.

- Alf, in chainmail and shield, with DEX 10 and no magical bonuses, has Armour Class 4, and Armour Type 4.
- Betty, in +3 chainmail, a +1 shield, and DEX 16, has Armour Class -2, but her Armour Type is 4, because the magic bonuses and DEX don't affect that.

A shield is a disadvantage in this form of combat, because it increases your armour type, but it's a very small change, so you might well want to hang onto it.

Almost everyone who played AD&D1e back in the eighties tried using the grappling, pummelling and overbearing rules *once*, and then abandoned them. If you're trying to recreate the authentic experience of the period, you can save time by abandoning them before use. Their only place is in a game devoted to research about the original rules intention, and I'm pretty sure they were not play-tested before publication.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been playing AD&D since the early 90s and I'm aware of how these rules would destroy the pace of an encounter at the table. But now that all of my current AD&D games are remote, I'm wondering if I can make a spreadsheet to make this usable at the table. I'm particularly interested in seeing how these rules allow "better players [to] ... neutralize [an] opponent's potential". This is less about creating a nostalgic experience and more about enriching the game play with tactical options given the "opportunity" I have today.

Comment: It sounds like the intention is that armor makes pummeling harder. Presumably because it hinders movement. Do you have insight into the `encumbrance = AC 10` portion?

Comment: @munk I am looking at my DMG right now, and checking for various errata from Dragon Mag 35 (which was IIRC the first published errata) and I can tell you what that note/asterisk means: it means that rings and such pose no obstacle to being pummeled, even if they are magical (which strikes me as bizarre; magic bracers would seem to protect one, I would think). Thus, if all that the one being pummeled is wearing is a ring/bracers/cloaks the "AC = 10" means that the base chance to pummel = 100% (per the opening text before the list of modifiers on page 72).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast So that's saying if the *defender* is encumbered, the base chance to hit them is 100%? The note seems to be referring to the *attacker's* AC.

Comment: @munk Not as I read it.  It means encumbrance for those items is equivalent to ac 10. Opponent value = AC times 10 is what is that is linked to. Why they chose the word "encumbrance" is not particularly clear. Those generally protective items (cloaks, rings, bracers) versus normal "to hit rolls against them"  provide no defensive advantage versus pummeling.  The encumbered state is referred to elsewhere. (PHB p. 101-102). (Thus ends my monthly quota of trying to make sense of that part of the AD&D 1e DMG ... we set it aside for a good and sufficient reason, as John points out)